# Accessing .svg symbols in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, svg

There was a lot of svg-files included when installing QGIS (`C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis-ltr\svg`), but the program can't really seem to find these. 
I've made sure the path is correct under Settings/Option/Systems and i've also tried adding them to the active profile folder (`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\svg`), and made sure the path there is correct as well.

When trying to import them using the Style Manager, i seem to only be able to choose xml-files.

How can I access the files which are included in the installation?

Comment: Do they show up in the layer styling panel when you change a marker style from a SImple Marker to an SVG marker? I don't see any SVG styles in Style Manager, but they do show up in the layer styling panel > symbol layer type > SVG Marker